# How to call setState/rebuild the UI of a Widget from an other when they are not parent/child?

Tags: flutter, setstate, riverpod

I have searchBar where i can click on a button (Widget 1) to update a path (StateProvider) and modify the support (a maze) that is displayed in the other widget. The issue is the UI dosent update in Widget 2, (unless I perfom some actions that call setState and see the path as want it). I want to click on this button and to see the update on Widget 2, so I am searching how to trigger a rebuild in Widget 2 when I click the button in Widget 1. I have read about Callbacks, but here i have very distant widgets that are not parent/child, I use flutter_riverpod ^2.3.6. I could propably use a CallBack to update the parent of both Widgets, but I would need to pass the callBack to a lot of intermediate widgets, and there must be some easier solution.

Her is parts of my Code :
The GridData file where I store Providers and create the maze :

```
final iMazeLengthProvider = StateProvider<int>((ref) => 30);
final itemNodeProvider =
    StateProvider<Node>((ref) => Node(Colors.red, Position(0, 0)));
final pathFinderProvider = StateProvider<List<Node>>((ref) => []);
final wallNodeProvider = StateProvider<List<Node>>((ref) => []);
final startPositionProvider =
    StateProvider<Node>((ref) => Node(Colors.green, Position(0, 0)));
final paintStatusProvider = StateProvider<bool>((ref) => false);


final jMazeLengthProvider = Provider<int>((ref) {
  final iMazeLength = ref.read(iMazeLengthProvider);
  return iMazeLength * iMazeLength;
});

class GridData extends StateNotifier<List<List<Node>>> {
  GridData(List<List<Node>> initialData) : super(initialData);

  late List<List<Node>> mazeMatrix;
  late int iMazeLength;
  late int jMazeLength;

  // Helper method to create the initial grid data.
  static List<List<Node>> createInitial(int iMazeLength) {
    int jMazeLength = iMazeLength * iMazeLength;

    // Maze initialization using generate function
    List<List<Node>> mazeMatrix = List.generate(iMazeLength, (int i) {
      List<Node> newList = [];

      for (int j = 0; j < jMazeLength; j++) {
        newList.add(new Node(notSelectedTileColor, Position(i, j)));
      }

      return newList;
    });

    return mazeMatrix;
  }
```

The button in Widget 1 that updates the path :

```
  ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    elevation: 5,
                    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    final path = pathAlgorithm.getPath(
                        ref.read(startPositionProvider.notifier).state,
                        ref.read(itemNodeProvider.notifier).state,
                        ref.read(wallNodeProvider),
                        ref.read(mazeMatrixProvider));

                    for (var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
                      path[i].color = Colors.yellowAccent;
                    }

                    ref.read(pathFinderProvider.notifier).state = path;
                    widget.onFindPath();
                  },
                  child: Text('Find Path'))
            ],
          )
        ],
```

and widget 2 that just display the maze, path, walls.. :

```
Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          // Wrap with Positioned.fill to take the available space
          child: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (context, constraints) {
              return GridView.builder(
                key: key,
                itemCount: jMazeLength,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: iMazeLength,
                  childAspectRatio: 100 / 100,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 1,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 1,
                ),
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  int x, y = 0;
                  x = (index / iMazeLength).floor();
                  y = (index % iMazeLength);
                  mazeMatrix[x][y].position.x = x;
                  mazeMatrix[x][y].position.y = y;
                  return CustomRenderWidget(
                      key: ValueKey<int>(index),
                      index: index,
                      child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              if (!Node.isStartNodePicked) {
                                mazeMatrix[x][y].setStartNode();

                                ref.read(startPositionProvider.notifier).state =
                                    mazeMatrix[x][y];
                              }
                              // } else if (!Node.isEndNodePicked) {
                              //   mazeMatrix[x][y].setEndNode();
                              //   ref.read(itemNodeProvider.notifier).state =
                              //       mazeMatrix[x][y];
                              // }
                              else {
                                mazeMatrix[x][y].setWallNode();
                                wallNode.add(mazeMatrix[x][y]);
                              }
                            });
                          },
                          child: AnimatedContainer(
                            curve: Curves.ease, //TODO Change the animation
                            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                            color: mazeMatrix[x][y].color,
                          )));
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: What about `Notification` class? 
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Notification-class.html

Comment: When you have state being shared by two or more widgets, it's time for state management.  I prefer Riverpod because it scales nicely to both small and large projects.